# HTTP Error 401 when trying to view SSRS 2019 subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

When I try to view the subscriptions to any SSRS report, I get a popup saying "Something went wrong".  I have reviewed the RSPortal logs and can see this error:

2023-05-26 09:02:18.9728|ERROR|229|OData exception occurred: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this please?  In all other regards (viewing reports etc.) SSRS is working as normal.  This is running on SQL Server 2019 by the way.

Thank you.

Comment: I edited UrlRoot in reportserver.config so it was no longer using https - i.e <UrlRoot>http://myserver/reportserver_live/</UrlRoot> and that has fixed the issue.  The web portal still uses SSL for the users so I am not quite sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fidding about I discovered that changing the UrlRoot parameter in the reportserver.config file so that it did NOT use HTTPS fixed the issue.

Old setting

```
<UrlRoot>https://myserver.mydomain.co.uk/reportserver_live/</UrlRoot>
```

New Setting

```
<UrlRoot>http://myserver/reportserver_live/</UrlRoot>
```

The web portal is still configured to use https so there is no impact to our end users.  I need to do some digging to understand why back-end API calls to edit data sources or manage subscriptions are not working with SSL but for the time being we are in good shape.